# Unable to Perform Upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am running into a strange error that is circular in nature. I just went to run a routine `sudo apt upgrade` and encountered the following error:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency
> tree... Done Reading state information... Done You might want to run
> 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages
> have unmet dependencies:  libzpool5linux : Depends: libzfs4linux (>=
> 2.0) but it is not installed  zfs-zed : Depends: libzfs4linux (>= 2.0) but it is not installed  zfsutils-linux : Depends: libzfs4linux (=
> 2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2) but it is not installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a
> solution).
```

Then, when I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

I receive the following error:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The
> following package was automatically installed and is no longer
> required:   ssl-cert Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it. The
> following additional packages will be installed:   libzfs4linux The
> following NEW packages will be installed:   libzfs4linux 0 upgraded, 1
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded. 10 not fully
> installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/232 kB of archives. After this
> operation, 655 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want
> to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 146025 files and
> directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
> .../libzfs4linux_2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> libzfs4linux (2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2) ... dpkg: error processing
> archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libzfs4linux_2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
> '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzfs.so.4.1.0', which is also in package
> libzfs5 2.2.2-1 dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal
> (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing: 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libzfs4linux_2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2_amd64.deb
> needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed E: Sub-process
> /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not sure where to go from here. Suggestions welcome.

Thank you